# CakePHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

As a CakePHP novice, I'm having this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and in my `LogsController` I have:

```
$conditions = array("Title.id" => $id);
$currentUser = $this->Title->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions), 'fields'=>array('user_id'));
```

Any idea, how I could solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place 'fields' in the array:

```
$currentUser = $this->Title->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields'=>array('user_id')));
```

Comment: As I do that I get this error, "Call to a member function find().." on the same line. :?

Comment: Then `Title` is not a model or not loaded in the context.

Comment: Thank you.. "$this->loadModel('Title');" did the job. :)

Comment: @deShushil - You can also add Title to the $uses array in your controller.